# Inferring generics for nested generic types

Tags: typescript

I have a generic type that can be arbitrarily nested, and I am struggling to get TypeScript to infer a string literal type where it currently will infer `string`.

```
// a type that derives some other type from the string type
type DeriveType<T extends string, Base extends string> = `${Base}${T}`;

// a type that can be arbitrarily nested
type Nested<T extends string, Base extends string = ''> = {
  value: T;
  derived(path: DeriveType<T, Base>): void;
  children?: Nested<string, `${Base}${T}`>[]; // what do I replace this with
};

declare function makeNested<T extends string>(nested: Nested<T>): Nested<T>;

makeNested({
  value: '/parent', // type of value is "/parent"
  derived(path) {}, // path correctly inferred as "/parent"
  children: [
    {
      value: '/child', // type of value is string, not "/child"
      derived(path) {}, // path incorrectly inferred as `/parent${string}`
      // I want it to infer as "/parent/child"
    },
  ],
});
```

Is there a way to make TypeScript infer this correctly, and if not, how should I refactor this.

Comment: I tried a dozen ways and nothing works; simultaneous generic and contextual type inference is tricky, and having it be recursive is making it trickier.  If I were to refactor this it would likely be as a curried function or builder, possibly like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMpg6N) shows, but it's not fun. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?